# Is there Android header file to use compass (orientation) in Firemonkey

Tags: firemonkey, compass

I tried to use orientationsensor in Firemonkey but in real devices no data was received. Compass3D sensor was found but all values stayd zeros or nans. Does anyone has header to access those sensors without Torientationsensor?

Comment: What device and RAD Studio version do you use?

Answer (score 0):

If you use XE9, you should call Start method of sensor to turn it on and get real info.

Comment: I used start - no success. Firemonkey apps cant find compass, other apps does. Even Embarcadero sample is not working.

Comment: Then please, create an issue at https://quality.embarcadero.com . Don't forget to mention device model and OS version.